Jupyter NoteBook 7.0.0 cannot connect to kernel - Kernel is disconnected - web socket errors on Chrome's console
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with python3 version 3.10.6 and with these installed packages:
 pip3 list | grep 'jupyter'
jupyter                   1.0.0
jupyter_client            8.6.2
jupyter-console           6.6.3
jupyter_core              5.7.2
jupyter-events            0.10.0
jupyter-lsp               2.2.5
jupyter_server            2.14.1
jupyter_server_terminals  0.5.3
jupyter-telemetry         0.1.0
jupyterhub                5.0.0
jupyterlab                4.2.2
jupyterlab_pygments       0.3.0
jupyterlab_server         2.27.2
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.11
 pip3 list | grep 'notebook'
notebook                  7.2.1
notebook_shim             0.2.4
 pip3 list | grep 'tornado'
tornado                   6.4.1
 pip3 list | grep 'ipykernel'
ipykernel                 6.7.0


I have JupyterHub configuration file jupyterhub_config.py with:
c.JupyterHub.bind_url = 'http://:8888/jhub/'

Then, I started jupyterhub with
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/jupyterhub -f /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py

Then, I can access https://domain_test.com/jhub and logged in with my Linux user account and it can authenticate to JupyterLab dashboard.

However, no matter what I tried, it says, "Kernel is disconnected"

and I cannot shift + Enter to run any python code on Jupyter notebook.
I checked my Chrome's console for developers and I saw many websocket errors like below:
jlab_core.ee83cc2a050b8046b604.js?v=ee83cc2a050b8046b604:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain_test.com/jhub/user/test_user/api/kernels/4d9a0de5-8bf0-4ed3-bcb6-ac501413f9a4/channels?session_id=779c2514-03be-44da-9eff-6fe67eec5da7' failed: 
_createSocket @ jlab_core.ee83cc2a050b8046b604.js?v=ee83cc2a050b8046b604:1
jlab_core.ee83cc2a050b8046b604.js?v=ee83cc2a050b8046b604:1 Connection lost, reconnecting in 2 seconds.
_reconnect @ jlab_core.ee83cc2a050b8046b604.js?v=ee83cc2a050b8046b604:1
jlab_core.ee83cc2a050b8046b604.js?v=ee83cc2a050b8046b604:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain_test.com/jhub/user/test_user/api/kernels/4d9a0de5-8bf0-4ed3-bcb6-ac501413f9a4/channels?session_id=424b2e39-8154-4827-bdf4-a9f12e8fc808' failed: 
_createSocket @ jlab_core.ee83cc2a050b8046b604.js?v=ee83cc2a050b8046b604:1
jlab_core.ee83cc2a050b8046b604.js?v=ee83cc2a050b8046b604:1 Connection lost, reconnecting in 0 seconds.
_reconnect @ jlab_core.ee83cc2a050b8046b604.js?v=ee83cc2a050b8046b604:1
jlab_core.ee83cc2a050b8046b604.js?v=ee83cc2a050b8046b604:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain_test.com/jhub/user/test_user/api/kernels/4d9a0de5-8bf0-4ed3-bcb6-ac501413f9a4/channels?session_id=c329221e-cb13-4a5b-b301-652359482c2e' failed: 

Please help, what is wrong with my system?

The reason for the kernel could not be connected is due to missing configuration for Websocket in Apache's proxy like in this below example
https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/configuration/config-proxy.html#apache
